# Using Venn Diagram Add-on with Tup

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, matplotlib-venn

I'm trying to do some stats homework in python and I wanted to create a Venn diagram of some different outcome spaces. I'm trying to pass two-element tuples to the Venn diagram and it doesn't seem to be too pleased about it. I really appreciate anyone who helps point me in the right direction!

...

```
combination_storage_container = [] 
for i in range(1,7):

    out = "(" + str(i) + ", " # making the initial string form
    print("\n")

    for j in range(1,7):
    
        out += (str(j) + ")") # adding the final piece
        print(out, end=" , ") # printing the piece 
        out = out[:4] 
        combination_storage_container.append(tuple([i,j]))
    
print("\n\n\n",combination_storage_container)
# IF I was making this a permanent piece of code, id do it in one loop
A_space = []
B_space = []
C_space = []
for combo in combination_storage_container:
    if combo[0] + combo[1] > 8: # <------ sum condition
        A_space.append(combo)
    if combo[0] == 2 or combo[1] == 2: # 2 condition
        B_space.append(combo)
    if combo[0] > 4: #<-------------- green bigger than 4 condition
        C_space.append(combo)
print("The A space is:\n", A_space)
print("The B space is:\n", B_space)
print("The C space is:\n", C_space)

venn3([A_space, B_space, C_space], ('A Space', 'B Space', 'C Space'))
plt.show()
```

...

I get this error:
...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [50], in <cell line: 16>()
     13 print("The B space is:\n", B_space)
     14 print("The C space is:\n", C_space)
---> 16 venn3([A_space, B_space, C_space], ('A Space', 'B Space', 'C Space'))
     17 plt.show()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib_venn\_venn3.py:345, in venn3(subsets, set_labels, set_colors, alpha, normalize_to, ax, subset_label_formatter)
    343     subsets = [subsets.get(t, 0) for t in ['100', '010', '110', '001', '101', '011', '111']]
    344 elif len(subsets) == 3:
--> 345     subsets = compute_venn3_subsets(*subsets)
    347 if subset_label_formatter is None:
    348     subset_label_formatter = str

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib_venn\_venn3.py:259, in compute_venn3_subsets(a, b, c)
    257     raise ValueError("All arguments must be of the same type")
    258 set_size = len if type(a) != Counter else lambda x: sum(x.values())   # We cannot use len to compute the cardinality of a Counter
--> 259 return (set_size(a - (b | c)),  # TODO: This is certainly not the most efficient way to compute.
    260     set_size(b - (a | c)),
    261     set_size((a & b) - c),
    262     set_size(c - (a | b)),
    263     set_size((a & c) - b),
    264     set_size((b & c) - a),
    265     set_size(a & b & c))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing three subsets like that, the first argument in the `venn3` function needs to be a list (or a tuple) of *sets*, so that their membership can be compared with the `|` (union) operator. You are currently passing a list of lists, so convert the lists to sets:

```
venn3([set(A_space), set(B_space), set(C_space)], ('A Space', 'B Space', 'C Space'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I would upvote but my reputation is too low. I feel so dumb because it literally has that in the example I grabbed from too, just applied to the lists prior to the Venn call.